# java extract elements separated by comma in a String

Tags: java, regex, string

i have a problem to extract a particular kind of element in a String.
The string is like this:

```
String input = [[2,3],[4,5],'hello',3,[3,[5,[6,7]]]],'hi',3
```

I'm using the split method to split the three elements of the string above, but i cannot find a regex that allows me to consider only the commas outside the list.

In a precedence question was suggested me to use this regex:

```
,(?![^\[]*[\]])
```

This regex works in some cases, but not in the case above.
I tried in different ways, but honestly i have not found a solution.

Comment: Please show what you have tried.

Comment: It's unclear what you're trying to extract. Can you show your expected output?

Comment: `i have a problem to extract a particular kind of element in a String` (What is that particular kind?). `I'm using the split method to split the three elements of the string above` (Which 3 elements?)

Comment: this is an interesting problem- but what if any of your strings contains the `[` character, or a comma?

Comment: 'hi', 3 and all the first part. The problem is that i cannot find a regex to avoid to consider the commas within the list.

Comment: are you required to use regex? an approach is building a tree by parsing the string-  you start from the root, `[` means you have child nodes, `,` means you have sibling nodes, and on `]` you return to the parent node-

Comment: No, i thought to use regex but it's not mandatory

Comment: If the previous answer did not work for you, you should not have accepted that answer. Now, that post is closed as a dupe and this one is plainly off-topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using regex, you just can achieve it using regex recursion but java's standard regex library doesn't support recursion.

But you can achieve what you are trying to do doing something similar to this:

```
String input = "[[2,3],[4,5],'hello',3,[3,[5,[6,7]]]],'hi',3";
String[] splited = input.split(",");
List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();

int brackets = 0;
String aux = "";
for (String string : splited) {
    char[] word = string.toCharArray();

    // count the brackets
    for (char c : word) {
        if(c=='['){
            brackets++;
        }
        else if(c==']'){
            brackets--;
        }
    }

    aux = aux + string;

    // if all opened brackets are closed
    if (brackets == 0) {
        result.add(aux);
        aux = "";
    } else {
        aux = aux + ",";
    }
}
// the list 'result' contains 3 elemets. Each one is one element separeted by comma
```

Comment: Thank you very much. You solved my problem. Honestly i had not thought to count the number of brackets; i focused all the time on an universal regex. Thanks again